# failed to install ubuntu or mint on DELL XPS 8900: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, dell-xps, acpi

When I tried to install ubuntu 19.10 on my DELL XPS desktop it shows at the console:

```
ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer
```

after looking up online I did these:

- upgrade my BIOS version;
- Change to install Min 18.3, and at its start, press F6 to switch to its command line and add this option: "acpi=off"

After that it went through and mint 18.3 seemed installed, only that when i restarted the computer at request, the GRUB driven menu showed up (because I had Windows 7 installed side by side) but nothing happened after that. The monitor is simply being black.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late answer but disabling the fast boot option in the BIOS has been shown to be effective with this issue.